# Centering image/entity in Crafty JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, craftyjs

I've got an instance of Crafty running on my page, 320x480.  I'm trying to develop a menu for a little game.  In the background of the menu scene, I want a pinwheel type effect that rotates.

Now, the rotation is not much of an issue, I already have tweens in the game that have things moving endlessly.  But I cannot for the life of me center the pinwheel in the middle of the canvas.

```
Crafty.defineScene("menu", function() {
Crafty.background("#000");

var bg = Crafty.e("2D, Canvas, Image, Tween")
    .image("img/pinwheel.jpg")
    .attr({x: 0, y: 0})
    .origin('center')
    .bind("Click", function(e) {
        Crafty.enterScene("game");
});
```

});

This is the code I have here.  I've not put the tween for rotation in yet.

I tried it as a DOM element instead of Canvas and tried to use CSS to shift it but Crafty seems to override this CSS.

The image in question is 2000 x 2000.  I could resize it to 320 x 480, but then when it's rotated the edges will appear.  Thus, the picture has to be square and also large enough to cover the canvas when rotated 45 degrees.  But I just can't figure out how to get the center of the image aligned with the center of the canvas!

Comment: Have you tried setting the element's height and width attributes? Also the min size an image should be to cover a playfield when rotated at the center is `var minWidthHeight = Math.floor( Math.sqrt( playWidth * playWidth + playHeight * playHeight ) ) + 2` so 2000 by 2000 is over kill, should be 578 by 578 pixels

Answer (score 0):

First of all resize your image to be the same size you want it to be displayed in your application.
Make sure that it is saved with a transparent / non-existent background layer in a `png` file.

Then you can go ahead and center the image using the viewport's width and height (they are specified either explicitly as arguments to `Crafty.init` or implicitly set to the window's bounds `Crafty.DOM.window.width` & `Crafty.DOM.window.height`):

```
.attr({x: viewportWidth/2 - imageWidth/2, y: viewportWidth/2 - imageHeight/2,
       w: imageWidth, h: imageHeight})
```

Take a look at the following snippet to see an rotating example in action.

```js
// setup Crafty
var gameWidth = 320,
    gameHeight = 480;

Crafty.init(gameWidth, gameHeight);
Crafty.background("#EEEEEE");

// the infinitely rotating, centered loading icon
var loadingIcon = Crafty.e("2D, Canvas, Image, Tween")
    .attr({x: gameWidth/2 - 230/2, y: gameHeight/2 - 230/2,
           w: 230, h: 230})
    .origin('center')
    .image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/OS_X_10.11_Beta_Beach_Ball.jpg")
    .bind("TweenEnd", function() {
      this.tween({rotation: this.rotation - 360}, 2000);
     });

// start rotating the icon
loadingIcon.trigger("TweenEnd");

// stop rotating the icon sometime later (e.g. when assets have loaded)
//loadingIcon.cancelTween("rotation");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crafty/0.6.3/crafty-min.js"></script>
```